# Why does the relation stand?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why does it stand that if $R$ is a relation, then:

$$R \subset dom(R) \times rng(R) \subset fld(R) \times fld(R)$$
?

Comment: What's $\text{fld}(R)$? The first inclusion (which should be $\subseteq$) is by definition of the entities involved.

Comment: @GitGud LOL we used exactly the same first letters. Note that some authors (and me) use $\subset$ and $\subsetneq$ as inclusion signs for subset and proper subset resp.

Comment: @AlexR I'm aware of that, I just think it's a very bad notation and I occasionally diss it. You don't use $<$ to denote 'less than or equal' so why use $\subset$ to denote less than and possibly equal?

Comment: @GitGud Mostly convenience: Most of the time you don't have to exclude $A=B$ in inclusion. It saves us three letters or a line on the whiteboard ^^... I guess it's a matter of preference. I'm just used to the "very bad notation" and to me it seems unnecessary to do that extra bar. But you can dispute about mathematical style all day long and not come to an agreement :)
Also I often need $A \subset\subset B$, saying that I can find a compact set $K$ such that $A\subset K\subset B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the definition of the sets.

Each $(x,y)\in R$ is such that $x$ is in the domain and $y$ is in the range. Therefore $(x,y)\in\operatorname{dom}(R)\times\operatorname{rng}(R)$. Since the field of a relation is the union of the domain and range, the right inclusion follows immediately.

Comment: So $\mathop{\rm fld}(R) := \mathrm{dom}(R) \cup \mathrm{rng}(R)$?

Comment: Yes, that is the definition I am familiar with.

Comment: Okay thanks, @GitGud and me were wondering what that might mean^^

Comment: @AsafKaragila So, when we say that $(x,y) \in dom(R) \times rng(R)$, does this mean that $x \in dom(R)$ and $y \in rng(R)$ ?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Also, how can we conclude that $dom(R) \times rng(R) \subset dom(R) \cup rng(R)$ ?

Comment: @evinda Not quite.
$$\mathrm{dom}(R) \times \mathrm{rng}(R) \subset (\mathrm{dom}(R) \cup \mathrm{rng}(R)) \times (\mathrm{dom}(R) \cup \mathrm{rng}(R))$$

Comment: @evinda: What does it mean, at all, when you say that $(x,y)\in X\times Y$?

Comment: Asaf Karagila $X \times Y=\{\langle x,y\rangle: x \in X, y \in Y\}$.. So, we can say that $\langle x,y \rangle \in X\times Y$.. But, can we also say that $(x,y) \in X \times Y$ ?

Comment: @evinda: What is $(x, y)$ to you?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is it an unordered pair? or am I wrong?

Comment: @evinda: Unordered pair is $\{x,y\}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So, with $(x,y)$ is it meant the same as with $<x,y>$?

Comment: @evinda: Yes, the two are often interchangeable (with a clear preference towards $\langle x,y\rangle$ when $(x,y)$ can be mistaken for an interval; and a preference towards $(x,y)$ when $\langle x,y\rangle$ might be mistaken with inner product).

Comment: @AsafKaragila A OK... So, because each element of $R$ belongs to $dom R \times rng R$, we have that $R$ is a subset of $dom R \times rng R$, right?

Comment: @evinda: Yes. That is the definition of $\subseteq$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I understand... Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Could I also ask you something else about set theory?
$$$$
If $x \neq y $, define the sets $\bigcup \langle x,y \rangle , \bigcup \bigcup \langle x,y \rangle$.

According to my notes, it is like that:

$$\langle x,y \rangle= \{ \{x\}, \{x,y\} \} $$

$$ \bigcup \langle x,y \rangle=\{x,y\} $$

$$ \bigcup \bigcup \langle x,y \rangle=x \cup y$$

Why is it $ \bigcup \bigcup \langle x,y \rangle=x \cup y$ and not $\bigcup \bigcup \langle x,y \rangle=\{x,y\}$ ?